# Typo3 classic mode generate composer file

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.7.x

short question. I got a site in Typo3 8.7 it was created in Classic Mode.
I installed a lot of extensions ( Realurl and stuff).

Now i want to port that to composer mode.
Is there a way to generate a composer.json/.lock from my site and then bring it over to my composer typo3 installation and let it download everything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a good list of steps you need to take for switching from classic to composer mode from Mathias Brodala.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46450927/1375055

Answer (score 0):

No, not to my knowledge. You'll have to kickstart your composer.json manually (or with the composer cli interface) and evolve it until you reach a similar combination of dependencies in your project.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Automated way of dooing this but a quick hack would be 
the following bash command do get a list of all packages names of the extensions

```
for f in $(ls typo3conf/ext); do echo "typo3-ter/$f"; done;
```