# How to install a "composer mode only" extension in "non-composer" TYPO3

Tags: composer-php, typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-8.7.x

The question says it all. I'd like to install https://github.com/lochmueller/staticfilecache in a non-composerified TYPO3 instance. What is the recommended procedure?

I thought I could download the source, cd into it and then do `composer install` on the command line and then I would get the complete extension. But I didn't see that worked.

Comment: Btw: the extension `staticfilecache` works without composer out of the box now https://github.com/lochmueller/staticfilecache/issues/39#issuecomment-352392263

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could ask the author to add support for the TYPO3 Classic Mode which basically means [embedding dependencies for extension packages](http://insight.helhum.io/post/148112375750/how-to-use-php-libraries-in-legacy-extensions) uploaded to the TER. There is no other way to achieve this in Classic Mode, thus obviously I strongly recommend [switching to Composer Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46450764/switch-to-composer-mode-in-running-instance/46450927#46450927).

Comment: Wow, your "Switching" instructions sound quite straightforward! But I can still use the extension manager to manage custom extensions if I do it, right? Regarding the `phar-composer` approach: is that also something I can do in a fork of the extension or does that go to "deep" into the knowledge of the extension?

Comment: You can use the Extension Manager to activate and deactivate extensions as well as configure them. Installation and removal must be done with Composer then.

And yes, you could fork the repository and add this yourself. As soon as you got it working I'd recommend a pull request to the original repository though. :-)